# jQuery Autocomplete binding dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

What I'm trying to do is have the auto-complete bind to newly added inputs. Here's how I have it coded:

```
<input size="80" type="text" class="ccnotes" name="dwg_notes[]" id="1200" />
```

This is the input used for the autocomplete. Now, When I add a new input I do the following:

```
$('a#more_notes').on('click',function(){
    var a = $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').clone(true);
    $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').after(a);  
});
```

And a new table row has been added with its own input.

However, before adding a new input, I bind autocomplete to the existing inputs of the table. I do so within a function:

```
function repnotes()
{
    $(function(){
        $(".ccnotes").each(function(index){

            var this_id = $(this).attr("id"); // current inputs id
            var new_id = parseInt(this_id)+index; // a new id
            $(this).attr("id", new_id); // change to new id 
            $(this).autocomplete({
                   source: function(request, response)
                   {
                       $.ajax({
                           url: getBaseURL()+"inspection/ajax/notes_json.php",
                           dataType: "json",
                           data: {note: request.term},
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               $(".ccnotes #"+new_id).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                               response($.map(data, function(item)
                               {
                                   return  {
                                       label: item.label
                                    };
                                }));
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function(event, ui)
                    {
                        $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                        $(".ccnotes").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');

                    }}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item){

                          return $( "<li></li>" ).data( "item.autocomplete", item ).append( "<a><strong>" + item.label + "</a>" ).appendTo( ul );

                 };
        }); 
    });
}
repnotes(); // initialize inputs
```

This works perfectly for the initial inputs. BUT, if I were to add the `repnotes()` function within:

```
$('a#more_notes').on('click',function(){
    var a = $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').clone(true);
    $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').after(a);  
      repnotes();  // ADD HERE
});
```

in order to re-initialize the inputs with their own `autocomplete`, only the ones that were there before remain initialized. The new ones don't seem to have `autocomplete` binded to them.

The only workaround to this that I have found is eliminating the function `repnotes()` and having to re-write the code used to initialize the autocomplete once when the page loads and again within the "add more lines" `function` but this is not efficient.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to "`destroy`" autocomplete before copying and re-initializing them again:

```
$('a#more_notes').on('click',function(){
    $(".ccnotes").autocomplete("destroy");  /// ADD HERE
    var a = $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').clone(true);
    $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').after(a);  
    repnotes(); // initialize

});
```

Now I can call the `repnotes()` function no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
counter = 0;
$(function () {
    $(".ccnotes").each(function (index) {
        repnotes($(this));
    })
    $('a#more_notes').on('click', function () {
        var a = $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').clone(true);
        $('table#dwg_notes tr:last').after(a);
        repnotes(a);
    });
})

function repnotes(el) {
    var this_id = el.attr("id"); // current inputs id
    var new_id = parseInt(this_id) + (++counter); // a new id
    el.attr("id", new_id); // change to new id 
    el.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: getBaseURL() + "inspection/ajax/notes_json.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    note: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".ccnotes #" + new_id).removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.label
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            $(".ccnotes").removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');

        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

        return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a><strong>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo(ul);

    };
}
```

Comment: Strangely, now when I first call the function, nothing gets initialized. However, when I add a new line, only the first one gets initialized but not the rest of the new ones nor the old ones...

Comment: Nevermind, the first ones get initialized, but none of the new ones.

Comment: I still have no luck with the new inputs. I just tried the code.